# Top to bottom sorting in multi page column RDL reports

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I'm trying to get a report to flow a list of sorted values in a multi-column tablix (see example).

I can get it to flow left to right like this:

```
Item 1   Item 2
Item 3   Item 4
```

etc.

but need it to flow top-bottom, left-right per page.

Any help most appreciated!

[image: exapmle flow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so the actual issue is that you can't use Columns in a sub report.  I'm now pre-rendering the subreport to a paged TIFF, then repeating those pages as PNGs to the main report.